# Combine the Queries for Plotting

Tags: mysql

How many i combine both queries so i have results from these columns for plotting :

```
COUNT(dismissals),COUNT(admissions), MONTH(Time)       data.
         Y       ,        Y        ,      X            coordinates to plot

SELECT COUNT(dismissals), MONTH(Time) 
   FROM  updates u
   JOIN  dismissals au
   ON u.updateid = au.updateid
   WHERE DATE(Time) BETWEEN '2013-07-14' and '2013-09-05' 
   GROUP BY MONTH(Time)  

SELECT COUNT(admissions), MONTH(Time) 
       FROM  updates u
       JOIN  admissions wu
       ON u.updateid = wu.updateid
       WHERE DATE(Time) BETWEEN '2013-07-14' and '2013-09-05' 
       GROUP BY MONTH(Time)
```

Comment: Which table has `time`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to approach this (assuming that `time` is from the `update` table) is:

```
SELECT  MONTH(Time) as Month,
        (select count(*) from dismissals d where u.updateid = d.updateid) as Dismissals,
        (select count(*) from admissions a where u.updateid = a.updateid) as Admissions
FROM  updates u
WHERE DATE(Time) BETWEEN '2013-07-14' and '2013-09-05' 
GROUP BY MONTH(Time)  ;
```

The advantage to this approach is that it doesn't filter out months with no admissions or dismissals.

Answer (score 0):

You can join your result sets

```
SELECT d.* , a.* FROM 
(SELECT u.updateid ,COUNT(dismissals) dismissals, MONTH(Time) month_time ,your_data_col
   FROM  updates u
   JOIN  dismissals au
   ON u.updateid = au.updateid
   WHERE DATE(Time) BETWEEN '2013-07-14' and '2013-09-05' 
   GROUP BY MONTH(Time)  
) d

JOIN 
(SELECT u.updateid, COUNT(admissions) admissions, MONTH(Time) month_time,your_data_col
       FROM  updates u
       JOIN  admissions wu
       ON u.updateid = wu.updateid
       WHERE DATE(Time) BETWEEN '2013-07-14' and '2013-09-05' 
       GROUP BY MONTH(Time)  
) a
ON (a.updateid =d.updateid)
```

Other solution is to use `UNION`

```
(SELECT null as admissions ,COUNT(dismissals) dismissals, MONTH(Time) month_time ,your_data_col
 FROM  updates u
 JOIN  dismissals au
 ON u.updateid = au.updateid
 WHERE DATE(Time) BETWEEN '2013-07-14' and '2013-09-05' 
 GROUP BY MONTH(Time)  
 ) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT COUNT(admissions) admissions,null as dismissals, MONTH(Time) month_time,your_data_col
FROM  updates u
JOIN  admissions wu
ON u.updateid = wu.updateid
WHERE DATE(Time) BETWEEN '2013-07-14' and '2013-09-05' 
GROUP BY MONTH(Time)  
)
```